# How to resolve errors produced by deleting google_maps_api.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-maps-v2

I am using this library for displaying directions: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/akexorcist/googledirection/sample/SimpleDirectionActivity.java. Previously I created a google maps activity, and the google_maps_api.xml was generated. I deleted this file because I don't believe I need it anymore, but now I get an error in my manifest file saying 
"No resources found that match the given name(at 'value' with value '@string/google_maps_key') Can I simply delete the meta data tage seen below or is there a better option to clean things up?

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Comment: Aguilar Don't delete the file. It is required, as it contains the key.

Comment: @Vicky I understand that, but I don't need the google maps activity that  I previously created. I'm using the version I provided in the link. Would I still need that xml file back?

Comment: To display the maps in your android app, the key is must. Even if you deleted the maps activity, the library you are using needs that key to display the maps. When you are displaying a map in your android app, what you are actually doing is making a request to google's android maps API, which requires the key. Go through this : [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

Comment: @Vicky so I should add the xml file back to resolve the issues? If that’s the case, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: First read the link I posted in the above comment. Then Read the documentation of the library you are using. You will be able to figure it out.